# Что делать если я не могу решить проблему IndentationError?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня выдает ошибку которую я не могу ни как решить, я уже менял код, переписывал, и т.п. Вот как выглядит ошибка полностью:
'''File "bot.py", line 14'''
'''markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)'''
^
'''IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level'''

```
import telebot
import configure
from telebot import types

client = telebot.TeleBot(configure.conf['token'])


@client.message_handler(commands = ['get_info', 'info'])
def get_user_info(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'ДА', callback_data = 'yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'НЕТ', callback_data = 'no')

    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Желаете узнать немного о себе?'
        reply_markup = markup_inline
        )
```

Comment: Для начала привести [mre]

Comment: Запятая перед вторым аргументом?

Comment: @dIm0n Да, запятая

Comment: "Да" в смысле в этом и была проблема? Перед 3 аргументом точнее

Comment: @dIm0n Кароче, это был баг, я его пофиксил, щас еще там из него 2 ошибки образовалось

Comment: Укажите эти новые ошибки  и исправленный код в вопросе тогда

Comment: как разработчики делают некоторые игры: итак, я пофиксил баг, теперь у меня их десять. STONKS